# Combination Search in Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, search, stored-procedures

I have several search Stored Procedures (by EmpName, by EmpCode, by Department),

Search by Name:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_SearchByName]
    @EmpName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    
    FROM Employee

    WHERE EmployeeName like '%'+ @EmpName +'%'

END
```

Search By EmpID:

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_SearchByID]
    @EmpID nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    
    FROM Employee

    WHERE EmployeeID like '%'+ @EmpID +'%'

END
```

Search by Department (I used combo box in C# to get this value):

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_SearchByName]
    @EmpDepartment nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT *
    
    FROM Employee

    WHERE EmployeeDepartment like '%'+ @EmpDepartment +'%'

END
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server.

The application:

I have 3 search options on my c# app, 2 text boxes (EmpName and EmpCode) and 1 combo box (Department).

How I use the search options:

At first, I will sort the table by Department, then input some EmpCode like 16xxxx. It will show like 200 results with the inserted Department and EmpCode, then I will narrow it down by EmpName. In addition, I could do it by sorting the table with EmpName first, then Department, then EmpCode.

Problem:

Let say, I sort the table with Department first, then EmpName and EmpCode. When I clear the EmpName (Department and EmpCode are remained), it should clear the search of EmpName and give the result back to be sorting of Department and EmpCode only, but it did not. It gave me a random result. In addition, when I have 3 search options cleared/empty, it gives me a random result as well.

The problem occurred when I tried to combine all of these search SPs to one SP by using AND, like:

```
SELECT *

FROM Employee

WHERE EmployeeDepartment like '%'+ @EmpDepartment +'%' AND EmployeeName like '%'+ @EmpName +'%' AND EmployeeID like '%'+ @EmpID +'%'
```

What is the correct way to combine all of these search SPs to one Stored Procedure?

Comment: I have edited my questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your syntax, it looks like you are using SQL Server.  Also, you haven't specified how you would search on only one column, if that is desired.  A typical solution would use `NULL` for the other search values, indicating that they are to be ignored.

To avoid problems with `NULL`, you can use the `CONCAT()` function.  This function ignores `NULL` values, whereas `+` returns `NULL` if any values are `NULL`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_SearchByName] (
    @EmpName nvarchar(100),
    @EmpID nvarchar(200),
    @EmpDepartment nvarchar(100)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT e.*
    FROM Employee e
WHERE e.EmployeeName LIKE CONCAT('%', @EmpName ,'%') AND
      e.EmployeeID LIKE CONCAT('%', @EmpID, '%') AND
      e.EmployeeDepartment LIKE CONCAT('%', @EmpDepartment, '%');
END;
```

A couple of comments on the approach you are taking.  First, because you have wildcards at the beginning of the `LIKE` pattern, this query cannot be optimized.  It is going to do a full table scan.  For performance, you might want to look at full text search capabilities in your database.

Second, I find that a table-valued function is much more convenient than a stored procedure for a "parameterized view".  You could then use the results in other queries.

Third, do not use an "sp" prefix on your stored procedures.  This is very close to `sp_`, which SQL Server uses to distinguish system stored procedures.  If you must have a prefix, using something different such as "usp_" (user stored procedure).  But it is not clear that a prefix has much utility, unless you are particularly fond of typing those letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all 3 searches in one stored procedure with 3 parameters and using `or` in where condition

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_SearchByName] 
@EmpName nvarchar(100),
@EmpID nvarchar(200),
@EmpDepartment nvarchar(100)
AS BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE (EmployeeName like '%'+ @EmpName +'%' or @EmpName is NULL) AND
(EmployeeID like '%'+ @EmpID +'%' or @EmpID is NULL) AND
(EmployeeDepartment like '%'+ @EmpDepartment +'%' or @EmpDepartment is NULL)
END
```

Tricks here is if you want to search with `EmployeeName` pass that `value` for `@EmpName` and send `NULL` for `@EmpId` and `@EmpDepartment`. If you want to search with `EmpId` pass that value for `@EmpID` parameter and send `NULL` for `@EmpName` and `@EmpDepartment` . To explain this look the condition for `or` logic when you send `NULL` for non searching parameter condition will become `NULL is NULL` which is always true.

Comment: This is not correct "NULL=NULL which is always true." Don't you mean `NULL is NULL` as your code implies?

Comment: Yes it should be `NULL is NULL` it works fine in `mssql` but i am not sure about `Mysql`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it did not work well with me... I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that in one procedure. And if this is `mysql` try changing your `like '%'+ @EmpName +'%'` to `LIKE CONCAT('%', @EmpName, '%')`.

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_Search]
    @EmpName nvarchar(100),
    @EmpID nvarchar(200),
    @EmpDepartment nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Employee
    WHERE (EmployeeName like CONCAT('%', @EmpName, '%')) or
    (EmployeeID like CONCAT('%', @EmpID, '%')) or
    (EmployeeDepartment like CONCAT('%', @EmpDepartment, '%'))
END
```

OR Like This by grouping your WHERE blocks using `CONCAT_WS`

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEmployee_Search]
    @SearchValue nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Employee
    WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', EmployeeName, EmployeeID, EmployeeDepartment) 
    LIKE CONCAT('%', @SearchValue, '%')
END
```

> The CONCAT_WS() function adds two or more expressions together with a separator.

[W3 Schools - MySQL CONCAT_WS() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_concat_ws.asp)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but it did not work well with me... I have edited my question